# Bottom Menu bar with submenu

Tags: android, submenu, bottomnavigationview, bottombar

Im using the BottomNavigationViewEx library to display a Bottom Menu Bar in my android app, the library works well and fixes many of the shortcomings of the standard BottomNavigationView.

The problem comes when as per requirements I need to show 7 options in the menu, with 4 options being the direct access to their respective functionality and a "More" option, that should show a submenu with 3 more options (similar to a toolbar with items with property `showAsAction="never"`)

Since the library does not admit more than 5 items and does not support submenus either I've been trying to implement a solution to no avail. Is there a way to implement this or any other bottom menu library that I could use that implements submenus (or lets me extend it to create a submenu)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though Adil's answer could have worked, I didn't go for it since it could create other problems. So I ended up making a Popup Menu anchored to the last menu item in the BottomNavigationView

Answer (score 0):

@Jeav148, you can take help from androidhive tab tutorial.
https://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

From this tutorial you can check the scrollable tabs, so you'll be able to add tabs as much menu items you want.
Just you need to use the tablayout inside RelativeLayout with property AlignParentBottom = "true" to show the tabs at bottom.

Comment: So basically disguise tabs as menu... Interesting. I'm not in love with this "hack" but might have to resort to it. Is there a way to make the "More" menu from tabs?